# How to copy files and their metadata (especially the content type)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am using javascript and jquery with SP Services. I have been copying images, video, documents, etc. between libraries without any issues using the CopyIntoItems method. However, I need to be able to copy the fields over as well for a miniature project and this method only seems to pull the proper name value over. How might I best complete this?

I want to be able to copy all media files in one library to another, but they need to get matching "Location", "Capture Date", and "Author" fields. Through a custom action (either VS or SPD) and a workflow, can I copy multiple (selected) items into a new library? I can do this for one item, manually, but many of these libraries have 500-700 files which need to be copied. The only batch method I know where this would be possible is through starting the workflow upon edit and changing in Datasheet view, but I am not seeing the functionality to "Create List item in **_"  where _** = library of a subsite.

Comment: Is this anyway to move to the sharepoint stackage?  I didn't use this site before so I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JSOM then you can enumerate each list item, then each field and set the target field value to the source field value. There are a lot of computed/read only fields that won't work though so you'll need to filter to the ones you want either using a query or if statements inside the loop.

Comment: I'm using js and jquery on a regular sharepoint page since I can'tuse SharePoint applications in my environment. Do I have to specify each field or can I just loop through each field that exists?

Comment: You can loop through each field of the source assuming the fields match in both lists. You'll want to use an if statement to ensure you don't grab computed field types (maybe some others, you'll probably need put a break point there and a watch to check what you're getting). You'll want to grab the field collection object from the list and enumerate through those.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SharePoint Designer workflow "Create List Item" action will only show Libraries/Lists in that site.It won't display Libraries/Lists of another sub site.